# Listen to a ajax post response from an iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

So I have this page that contains a form that is an iframe(different domain). After sending the form, I get a confirmation in the iframe. What I need is to get that post response from that iframe. In Chrome's dev tools, in the Network tab and XHR only, I can see that https://my-website/api/v2/booking/reservations has a response.

Basically I need to know when I get a response from the form sent from that iframe.  After clicking send form, I get the confirm(post response) and that's all I need. I tried using Javascript's event listener for post message where the origin is the iframe but all it returns in its data property is the height of the iframe and it varies with every response. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: CORS restrictions  will prevent you from doing this, unless the third-party site you're framing explicitly allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using Javascript's event listener for post message where the origin is the iframe but all it returns in its data property is the height of the iframe and it varies with every response

This is because the page you are putting in the frame is sending that information to the parent (so it can dynamically adjust the height of the iframe).

If you want to know something else about the page (such as when it has made an HTTP request) then you need to change **that** page so it sends (using `postMessage`) the information you need.

You can't collect arbitrary data from other people's websites just by putting them into a frame. That would be a horrible security problem. You can only collect the data they send you.